# Fatal error: Uncaught exception

Tags: php

i have this error...

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'LogicException' with message 'Function 'PHPMVC\LIB\Autoload::autoload' not callable (non-static method PHPMVC\LIB\Autoload::autoload() cannot be called statically)' in C:\xampp\htdocs\mohamaed\MVC\app\lib\autoload.php:11 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\mohamaed\MVC\app\lib\autoload.php(11): spl_autoload_register('PHPMVC\LIB\Auto...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\mohamaed\MVC\public\index.php(9): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\mohamaed\MVC\app\lib\autoload.php on line 11

the code :

```
spl_autoload_register(__NAMESPACE__ .'\Autoload::autoload');
```

Comment: Have you actually read the error message? `PHPMVC\LIB\Autoload::autoload` is not a static method so cannot be called statically

Answer (score 0):

The error message makes it reasonably clear... you have registered `PHPMVC\LIB\Autoload::autoload` as a static autoloader callback but this method is **not** static.

You will need to use the array object method call syntax instead

```
$autoload = new Autoload(); // pass whatever args this actually requires
spl_autoload_register([$autoload, 'autoload']);
```

See http://php.net/manual/language.types.callable.php